# Swift 3 move View when keyboard is shown - wrong KeyboardSize

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm currently struggling with moving my view when iOS is showing/hiding the keyboard.
(Sorry, didn't know how to format code highlighting)

I implemented the following observers:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And these functions:

```
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
      if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height/2
      }
    }
  }

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
      if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height/2
      }
    }
}
```

And I added an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
  func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

  func dismissKeyboard() {
   view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

So all this together works pretty well.
However, I have a problem once the keyboards thinks it'd be a good idea to show the word suggestions. The keyboard gets higher and the view wanders down too far.
This mostly happens when the users switch from a Numbers-Only keyboard into another textfield where it's a normal keyboard (sometimes with the suggestions).
So, is there a way to know whether the keyboard currently shows the word suggestions (or whatever other 'normal' height divergence)?
I thought about using a global var for the keyboard height of the **keyboardWillShow** function but that won't work since I'd either move to far or to less when they switch between textfields with different keyboard heights (see number pad).
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Ah! I think storing the **willShowKeyboard**-height in a global var and comparing it to the **willHideKeyboard**-height might work. I'm still open for smoother solutions though!

Comment: Why am I beeing downvoted? I had a problem and found a fix myself. Sometimes I don't get SO users.

Answer (score 0):

The key UIKeyboardFrame**Begin**UserInfoKey doesn't give you the final size - as the name hints "Begin".

Instead try using it's sister UIKeyboardFrame**End**UserInfoKey - which will give you the keyboards final size after end animation.

Note it doesn't take rotation into account https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uikeyboardframeenduserinfokey

Comment: This doesn't make a difference unfortunately. It's still different keyboard sizes when I switch from a normal textfield (with word suggestions) to let's say a number unput. So, I need a way to get the the keyboard size without the word suggestions part.

Answer (score -1):

I ended storing the keyboardHeight from **keboardWillShow** into a global var and take that variable to move it back in **keboardWillHide**. And I'm checking whether the last keyboardHeight is equal to the current to move my view if needed.
Not too beautiful. But hey, it works!

```
// keyboardHeight is a global var.

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 ||
      (keyboardHeight != keyboardSize.height/2)
    {
      self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
      self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height/2
      keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height/2
    }
  }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
  _ = keyboardSize.height/2 // to surpress warnings...
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
      self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardHeight //keyboardSize.height/2
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know about that **self.view.frame.origin.y = 0** in **keyboardWillShow**. I think I'll consider only moving it the difference instead setting it to 0 each time. But at the moment everythink works as it should.